# Displaying foreign key values

Tags: python, django

My models.py looks like that:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

class OrderItem(models.Model): (item in the cart)
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    label = models.ManyToManyField(Label, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

class Bike(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ManyToManyField(Brand)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size, blank=True)

class Accessory(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand_accessory = models.ManyToManyField(BrandAccessory)
```

So currently the field `item` in my `OrderItem` model displays the title and quantity of the item in `Item` model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
```

`Item` is connected with `OneToOneField` with `Bike` and `Accessory`.
Is it possible to display the brand and size of the `Bike` if its added to `OrderItem` and `brand_accessory` if `Accessory` is added to the `OrderItem`?

It would look like {quantity} {item.title} (if bike)> {bike.brand} {bike.size} (if accessory)> {accessory.brand_accessory}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if your `item` got OneToOneField you need

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        if hasattr(self.item, 'bike'):
            #get value you need like: self.item.bike.brand
        if hasattr(self.item, 'accessory'):
            #get value you need like: self.item.accessory.brand_accessory
        return #get values you need together
```

Comment: Do I construct my `__str__()` inside the if statement? And I am getting error, that `self` is not defined

Comment: I have tried if hasattr(item, 'bike'), but it doesn't work either

Comment: Did you add `self` to str parameters? `def __str__(self):`. If statments should be inside `__str__` function.

Comment: do I return the value in the if statements? How do I display the value that are together?

Comment: You can make string variable, concatenate values in it in if statementes, and at the end return this variable as a result of `__str__` function.